# if else statement in while loop, where if else statement determines when while loop stops

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

```
var userInput = prompt("type something with or without double spacing");
var errorSpaces = [];
var maxSpaceCount = [];
var doneOnce = 0;
var done = 0;
var size;
var tempArray = [0, 0];
while (done === 0) {
    if (doneOnce === 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i<size; i++) {
            size = userInput.length - 1;
            if (userInput.substr(i, 2) == "  ") {
            userInput.replace(userInput.substring(i, j), userInput[i]);
            errorSpaces.push(0);
            }   
        }
        doneOnce = 1;
        maxSpaceCount.push(0);
    } else if (doneOnce === 1 && tempArray.length != 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i<size; i++) {
            tempArray = [0];
            size = userInput.length - 1;
            if (userInput.substr(i, 2) == "  ") {
                userInput.replace(userInput.substring(i, j), userInput[i]);
                tempArray.push(0);
            }
            doneOnce = 2;
        }
        maxSpaceCount.push(0);
    } else {
    done = 1;
    }
}
alert("done");
```

This loops at the second for loop rather than finishing. I know it probably isn't the best way to do it, but how could I make the 'else if' work so that when there are no more double spaces, it will go to the final else?

I am trying to eliminate any multiple spaces by iteratively replacing double spaces with single spaces, then re-reading to replace further double (previously triple) spaces, etc.

Comment: Just for clarification, your are trying to remove all double spaces from a user supplied string, is that correct? What is the point of tempArray?

Comment: Is this what you want? `"type something with or without double spacing".replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');`

Comment: That's right, it's meant to iterate replacing double spaces with single spaces until no multiple spaces exist

Comment: regex to the rescue! https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with `tempArray` but the logic bug is probably there. Quick question: how will this question help others in the future? Looks like a helpdesk/debugging post to me...

Comment: tried to set up a fiddle with your code.. now I can't close the tab. I will leave it open forever

Comment: `It is meant to count the errors, so I can't see regex working` Please, you're not making any sense. Count what errors? How? Why? Which bit of code does that? Be less vague.

Comment: Regex is IDEAL for this, including if you want to _count_ how many occurrences of double, triple or how every many spaces

Comment: Indeed. OP is reinventing regex and getting it wrong :)

Comment: @plalx I was initially going to select yours because it mentioned regex first, but it didn't quite answer the question (which was very unclear... :/), whereas the other answer which was given later did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way , way too much code if your goal is to replace any double (or more spaces) with a single space

try regex

```
var userInput = prompt("type something with or without double spacing");
userInput  = userInput.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
alert("done");
```

although not quite sure what you are trying to do with `tempArray` as it doesn't seem to make sense.

---

**EDIT**

There appears to be some indication that there is a requirement to *count* how many occurrences of 2 or more spaces, so using the below will give you the count. The reason for the `||` bit is because if none are found, it will return null, `|| []` will change the null to empty array, so the length of it will be zero. ***Thanks to @RobG***

```
var countOfMultipleSpaces = (userInput.match(/\s{2,}/g) || []).length;
```

I'm sure it goes without saying that you have to do this before you replace them all

Comment: I'll edit the question. I wasn't clear, sorry. I am trying to eliminate any multiple spaces, so just removing double spacing wouldn't work.

Comment: This replaces 2 or more spaces with one space, as I mentioned in the first sentence

Comment: @user2024463 It what way it "wouldn't work"? What does this answer's code do that you don't want it to do? Be clear and precise about your requirements, ideally with examples. (Perhaps you're not aware that `{2,}` means "two _or more_"; read the documentation before rushing to negative conclusions!)

Comment: I thought I'd be putting in way too many lines of code if I included a counter for the amount of double spaces 'mistakes' made... so I sort of botched this question. Edited with some context previously left out. I've made this process so convoluted, so sorry about that.

Comment: Edit your question (theres a little `edit` under the question to the left), and be clearer with exactly what you are wanting

Comment: @user2024463: If you want to find out how many instances of "two or more spaces" exist in the input, use _the exact same regex_! And count the matches. Why do you think that won't work? I'm curious

Comment: Because I'm an idiot. Going to select this regex answer as correct (seeing as it applies directly to what I said I needed to do) and reconsider my life!

Comment: Note that if there are no double spaces, *match* will return *null* and attempting *null.length* will throw an error. Consider `(userInput.match(/\s{2,}/g) || []).length` or even `userInput.split('  ').length - 1`.

Comment: According to OP current logic, the for loop code inside else-if will never execute.

Because, Inside the for loop , you are referencing size which is a local variable to the above if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
"type     something  with or   without    double spacing".replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
//"type something with or without double spacing"
```